# Using recursion in a class

Tags: python, syntax

I'm practicing for an exam and trying to figure this out. I'm just not exactly what to do with the add method. This is what I have so far:

```
class recursion:
    def __init__(self, lst=[]):
        self.lst = lst

    def add(self, x, y):
        return x + y

    def recurs(self):
        if len(self.lst) == 1:
            return lst[0]
        else:
            return self.lst[0].add(self.recurs(lst[1:])
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do exactly?

Comment: Why do you have an add method on the class?

Comment: @Patrick also why don't you just use `sum` instead of making your own `add` method.

Comment: @jamylak I think @Omerta is practicing recursion for an exam. Otherwise, using `sum` would be the way to go.

Comment: @Oliver I thought the add method just added numbers, nvm misread it then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to recursively get the sum of the list:

Essentially, `recursive_sum_helper` keeps calling itself with smaller lists:

> sum(1, 2, 3, 4) = 1+sum(2,3,4) = 1+( 2 + sum(3,4) ) = ...

```
class recursive_summer:
    def __init__(self, lst=[]):
        self.lst = lst
    def recursive_sum(self):
        return self.recursive_sum_helper(self.lst)
    def recursive_sum_helper(self, a_lst):
        if len(a_lst) == 1:
            return a_lst[0]
        else:
            first_element = a_lst[0]
            list_without_first_element = a_lst[1:]
            return first_element + self.recursive_sum_helper( list_without_first_element )

r = recursive_summer([1,2,3,4])
r.recursive_sum()
```

The output is 10.

Hope this helps with whatever problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

it's recursion way to do this, but more clean:

it uses [pop](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) method from list

```
class rec(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.sum = 0

    def recur(self, list):
        if len(list) > 0:
            self.sum += list.pop()
            self.recur(list)
        else:
            return self.sum
```

using:

```
>>> from code import rec
>>> a = rec()
>>> b = [1,2,3]
>>> print a.recur(b)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to get sum of the list without recursion, but more faster and effective:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> sum(a)
6
>>>
```

Comment: If the question says recursion as the 2nd word, you shouldn't post this as an answer.

Comment: it's not actually answer, but it's may be helpful info for exam preparation

Comment: it really should be a comment then but you don't have enough rep to comment on the question so never mind.