# How to flatten a hetrogenous list of list into a single list in python?

Tags: python, list, flatten

I have a list of objects where objects can be lists or scalars. I want an flattened list with only scalars.
Eg:

```
L = [35,53,[525,6743],64,63,[743,754,757]]
outputList = [35,53,525,6743,64,63,743,754,757]
```

P.S. The answers in this question does not work for heterogeneous lists. [Flattening a shallow list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python)

Comment: this works if pop() returns a only one scalar at a time http://stackoverflow.com/a/10546929/1321404  you can modify this code with if len(returned_pop_element)>1 then call recursive function again for returned_pop_element(list).

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828123/nested-list-and-count/5828872

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/40857703/4531270

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a relatively simple recursive version which will flatten any depth of list

```
l = [35,53,[525,6743],64,63,[743,754,757]]

def flatten(xs):
    result = []
    if isinstance(xs, (list, tuple)):
        for x in xs:
            result.extend(flatten(x))
    else:
        result.append(xs)
    return result

print flatten(l)
```

Comment: I think I can make it `isinstance(xs,collections.Iterable) and not isinstance(xs,str)` so that it includes `set` and other possible iterables as well.

Comment: `and not isinstance(xs,basestring)` for python < 3, but yes good idea

Answer (score 6):

it could be done neatly in one line using `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
np.hstack(l)
```

you end up with an ndarray

```
array([  35,   53,  525, 6743,   64,   63,  743,  754,  757])
```

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> data = [35,53,[525,6743],64,63,[743,754,757]]
>>> def flatten(L):
        for item in L:
            if isinstance(item,list):
                for subitem in item:
                    yield subitem
            else:
                yield item


>>> list(flatten(data))
[35, 53, 525, 6743, 64, 63, 743, 754, 757]
```

Here is a one-liner version for code-golf purposes (it doesn't look good :D )

```
>>> [y for x in data for y in (x if isinstance(x,list) else [x])]
[35, 53, 525, 6743, 64, 63, 743, 754, 757]
```

Comment: The first version breaks strings into characters, I don't think that is desirable.

Comment: @JanneKarila It doesn't say there will be strings.

Comment: If you use `hasattr(item, '__iter__')` you can avoid the string problem without limiting the range of iterables.

Comment: @JoelCornett The question only mentions the use of `list` so I will just use `isinstance` as the other answers have also done.

Answer (score 3):

```
l = [35,53,[525,6743],64,63,[743,754,757]]
outputList = []

for i in l:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        outputList.extend(i)
    else:
        outputList.append(i)
```

Comment: @jamylak, thanks for editing, but i like two spaces for indentation :-(

Comment: @jamylak, thanks for the ref. I always thought that the recommendation is to use spaces. Did not know it was 4 spaces.

Comment: Yeah but of course they are filled in by the editor when you press tab anyway. It is usually set to 4 or 3 by default. Also for some reason i cannot write @Vikas at the beginning of my comments, I don't know why it is not letting me...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a oneliner, based on [the question you've mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406121/flattening-a-shallow-list-in-python):

```
list(itertools.chain(*((sl if isinstance(sl, list) else [sl]) for sl in l)))
```

**UPDATE:** And a fully iterator-based version:

```
from itertools import imap, chain
list(chain.from_iterable(imap(lambda x: x if isinstance(x, list) else [x], l)))
```

Comment: It's a oneliner, it's not meant to be pretty.

Comment: Well in that case i think i have a smaller one liner, i will post it.

Comment: Additionally, `sum((i if isinstance(i, list) else [i] for i in L), [])`

Comment: @JoelCornett +1 That is what I thought of as well but i didn't like it since it has to construct a new list each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

```
outputList = []
for e in l:
    if type(e) == list:
        outputList += e
    else:
        outputList.append(e)

>>> outputList
[35, 53, 525, 6743, 64, 63, 743, 754, 757]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def nchain(iterable):
    for elem in iterable:
        if type(elem) is list:
            for elem2 in elem:
                yield elem2
        else:
            yield elem
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive function that will allow for infinite tree depth:

```
def flatten(l):
    if isinstance(l,(list,tuple)):
        if len(l):
            return flatten(l[0]) + flatten(l[1:])
        return []
    else:
        return [l]

>>>flatten([35,53,[525,[1,2],6743],64,63,[743,754,757]])
[35, 53, 525, 1, 2, 6743, 64, 63, 743, 754, 757]
```

I tried to avoid isinstance so as to allow for generic types, but old version would infinite loop on strings. Now it flattens strings correctly (Not by characters now, but as if it's pretending a string is a scalar).

Comment: I would not expect strings to be flattened (broken to single characters).

Comment: Technically strings are iterables, which is why I included it. It does seem kind of odd when I look at it more closely.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = [35,53,[525,6743],64,63,[743,754,757]]
>>> K = []
>>> [K.extend([i]) if type(i) == int else K.extend(i) for i in L ]
[None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> K
[35, 53, 525, 6743, 64, 63, 743, 754, 757]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is only for your specific situation (scalars within lists) and assumes the scalars are integer. It is a terrible solution but it is incredibly short.

```
outputlist = map(int,",".split(str(L).replace("[","").replace("]","")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. Take advantage of recursion.

```
def flatten(nst_lst, final_list):

    for val in nst_lst:
        if isinstance(val, list):
            flatten(val, final_list)
        else:
            final_list.append(val)
    return final_list

#Sample usage
fl_list = []
lst_to_flatten = [["this",["a",["thing"],"a"],"is"],["a","easy"]]

print(flatten(lst_to_flatten, fl_list))
```