# How to remove formatting in python

Tags: python

is it possible to remove all the formatting from an output

currently i get the values  :

```
 ((4,), (4,), (88, 59, 21, 38))
```

displayed in the terminal, however is there a way to strip away the brackets so i only get the values ?

I know it should be simple but cant see to find it on google

Thanks

to get this i am using the command :

```
print "Header : ",  circ_id, command, ip
```

where where circ_id etc have been derived from earlier on in the application from unpacking a packet for example the ip was derived from :

```
ip = struct.unpack(byte_string, payload[start:end])
```

so i guess the question is how in python can you merge various tuples into a single tuple ?

Comment: It would help if you told us what you were doing to _get_ that output.

Comment: You can flatten the array and then print the flattened array, which will have fewer brackets: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632111/how-to-flatten-a-hetrogenous-list-of-list-into-a-single-list-in-python/10632267

Comment: You are getting the result in form of a tuple. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences Try playing with the tuples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> new = []
>>> a
((4,), (4,), (88, 59, 21, 38))
>>> for i in a:
...     for j in i:
...         new.append(j)
... 
>>> new
[4, 4, 88, 59, 21, 38]

>>> #If you want result back in tuple

... 
>>> tuple(new)
(4, 4, 88, 59, 21, 38)
```

Answer (score 0):

One more if I the input is string

```
import re
re.sub('.', lambda m : {'(':'',')':''}.get(m.group(),m.group()),'((4,),(4,),(88,59,21,38))')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a format string.

```
In [1]: circ_id, command, ip = (4,), (4,), (88, 59, 21, 38)

In [2]: fs = "Header: {}, {}, {}.{}.{}.{}"

In [3]: print fs.format(circ_id[0], command[0], ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3])
Header: 4, 4, 88.59.21.38
```