# How to completely flatten a list in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, python-itertools, flatten

Flattening lists of lists is a well-known problem but how does one flatten a **list of lists of lists** in the most **pythonic** way? My ultimate goal is to create a numpy array as follows:

```
[In]: mylist = [[[1,2,3], [4]], [[5,6], [7,8]]]
[Out]: array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
              [5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

but even just completely flattening into a long list will do (can be easily converted into the right-shaped array anyway). A typical output array will have dimensions (10000, 10) so looping through the rows-to-be is very inefficient. All ideas will be appreciated!

***(edit)*** Best solution I can think of:

```
import itertools

for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mylist[i] = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(mylist[i]))
np.array(mylist)
```

Comment: Just to understand the problem how could you have a looping solution to solve your sample case?

Comment: In fact many solutions which look tempting at first return `array([list([1, 2, 3]), list([4]), list([5, 6]), list([7, 8])], dtype=object)`

Comment: This is also one of my favourites: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10632307/7919597

Comment: `list(map(list, map(itertools.chain.from_iterable, mylist)))`?

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to use `numpy.append`:

```
import numpy as np

rows = [[[1, 2, 3], [4]], [[5, 6], [7, 8]]]
result = np.array([np.append(value[0], value[1:]) for value in rows])

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]]
```

The function `numpy.append` flattens value[1:]. One alternative is to use `concatenate` and `ravel`:

```
rows = [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]]]
result = np.array([np.concatenate(value).ravel() for value in rows])
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[[1 2 3]
 [4 5 6]]
```

The `concatenate` function join a sequence of arrays and `np.ravel` returns a contiguous flattened array. You could change `np.ravel` by [np.flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html).

Comment: Nice idea but this fails when the rows have more than two lists in them... `rows = [[[1], [2], [3]], [[4], [5], [6]]]` throws a TypeError.

Comment: append does a lot of relocation. It is not amortized at all, unlike list append and extended. Still a good thought.

Comment: Updated my answer